# How to remove node_modules files from Github?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I forgot to add .gitignore file ,that's why when i push code to git hub my node_modules file have sent to git hub ,now i want to remove it From my github.

Answer (score 1):

At first create &add the.gitignore and type node_modules  inside the .gitignore file the file  go to the CMD of your File then type the Commands Below:

git   rm   -r   --cached   node_modules

git   commit   -m"Removing node_modules file"

git   push   -f